# Reading from an SCXML file using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, fsm

I am currently working on a project whereby I need to extract the states and relevant transitions from an XML file. Currently, I can successful extract all of the correct information, but the nested transitions aren't linked to their states. Apologies for the strange XML file, it was made quickly as an example.

This is the code that I have which is used to extract the information from the XML file

```
 using System;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Xml.Linq;

 namespace LINQTesting
 {
  internal class Program
 {
  private static void Main(string[] args)

   {

     var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:/ProjectC/XmlConverterTest.xml");
     xdoc.Descendants("state").Select(a => new
        {
           id = a.Attribute("id").Value

        }).ToList().ForEach
        (a =>
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + a.id);

        });



     xdoc.Descendants("transition").Select(d => new
     {
        action = d.Attribute("event").Value,
        target = d.Attribute("target").Value
     }).ToList().ForEach
       (d =>
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Action Name: " + d.action);
          Console.WriteLine("Target: " + d.target);
       });

   }
  }
}
```

Below is my XML file:

```
<statemachine>

<state id="WaitForSelection">
    <transition event="Passed" target="AddTo50pBox"/>
</state>

<state id="10p Entered" subworkflow="ValidateCoin">
    <transition event="Passed" target="AddTo10pBox"/>
</state>

<state id="20p Entered" subworkflow="ValidateCoin">
    <transition event="Passed" target="AddTo20pBox"/>
    <transition event="Failed" target="NESTED transition"/>
</state>

<state id="50p Entered" subworkflow="ValidateCoin">
     <transition event="Passed" target="AddTo50pBox"/>
</state>

<state id="RejectCoin">
     <transition event="CoinRejected" target="DispenseCoin"/>
</state>

<state id="End State">
     <transition event="CoinRejected" target="RejectCoin"/>
</state>

</statemachine>
```

At the moment, I am not focused on being able to create the state machine. I just need to be able to provide it with correctly formatted information. 
I have done two separate Descendants as the search was not able to cope with nested transitions within the "state" search. I'm fairly certain this is a simple fix, just getting a foreach / for loop to correctly print out the values.

So ideally, the output would read as below for each state, instead of listing off all the states first, then the transitions afterward.

State: "WaitForSelection"

Transitions: "Passed" , "Addto50PBox"

Instead of

State: "WaitForSelection"

State: "10P Entered"

Transitions: "Passed" , "Addto50PBox"

Transitions: "Passed" , "Addto10PBox"

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Process the nodes in a single pass.

```
foreach (var state in xdoc.Descendants("state"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("State: " + state.Attribute("id").Value);
    foreach (var transition in state.Elements("transition"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Transitions: " + transition.Attribute("event").Value
            + " " + transition.Attribute("target").Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```